# does windows handle the opcode different?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, disassembly, opcode

(btw this ist my first question here, so I dont know any guidelines)

Im trying to learn reading the pure opcodes (I do not know the exact term) of Programms on x-86-architectur (intel i5-7400) but if I look at an .exe-file there are huge rows with the same (hexadicimal) numbers and it doesnt make much sense. Last I created a .exe-file from a simple .cpp-file with the gnu compiler on the cmd. It doesnt make thrifty things but writes a word in the console and ask a word from the user to write in the console:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    std::cout<<"aaahhhhhhhhh"<<std::endl;
    char a;
    std::cin>>a;
    return 0;
}
```

the .exe-file looks as follows in binary form:
4d 5a 90 20 03 20 20 20 04 20 20 20 ff ff 20 20 b8 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 40 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 80 20 20 20 0e 1f ba 0e 20 b4 09 cd 21 b8 01 4c cd 21 54 68 69 73 20 70 72 6f 67 72 61 6d 20 63 61 6e 6e 6f 74 20 62 65 20 72 75 6e 20 69 6e 20 44 4f 53 20 6d 6f 64 65 2e 0d 0d 0a 24 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 50 45 20 20 64 86 13 20 24 97 09 62 20 86 01 20 b6 05 20 20 f0 20 26 20 0b 02 02 25 20 18 20 20 20 40 20 20 20 02 20 20 d0 14 20 20 20 10 20 20 20 20 20 40 01 20 20 20 20 10 20 20 20 02 20 20 04 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 05 20 02 20 20 20 20 20 20 40 02 20 20 06 20 20 cf ea 02 20 03 20 60 01 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 10 20 20 20 20 20 20
...

and is very long of course (there is much left).

I was reading the first lines. As you can see (or let traduce; I took this to examine if I was correct and if I wasnt it was always the more correct one: [the link](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2)) it first pops the r10 from the stack. In the rex byte 01001101 the 3th bit is set, but not used because there isnt any modrm byte in this kind of the pop-operation. Then the opcodes make strange thing with and and the register and it do not look like instruction but like a queue of numbers. There are nops and many false opcodes interrupts. So I now wonder, how this comes since the code starts with the first bit. Below it begins to do what it have to but the first lines? Why?

```
0:  4d 5a                   rex.WRB pop r10
2:  90                      nop
3:  20 03                   and    BYTE PTR [rbx],al
5:  20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
7:  20 04 20                and    BYTE PTR [rax+riz*1],al
a:  20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
c:  ff                      (bad)
d:  ff 20                   jmp    QWORD PTR [rax]
f:  20 b8 20 20 20 20       and    BYTE PTR [rax+0x20202020],bh
15: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
17: 20 40 20                and    BYTE PTR [rax+0x20],al
1a: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
1c: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
1e: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
20: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
22: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
24: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
26: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
28: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
2a: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
2c: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
2e: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
30: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
32: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
34: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
36: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
38: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
3a: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
3c: 80 20 20                and    BYTE PTR [rax],0x20
3f: 20 0e                   and    BYTE PTR [rsi],cl
41: 1f                      (bad)
42: ba 0e 20 b4 09          mov    edx,0x9b4200e
47: cd 21                   int    0x21
49: b8 01 4c cd 21          mov    eax,0x21cd4c01
4e: 54                      push   rsp
4f: 68 69 73 20 70          push   0x70207369
54: 72 6f                   jb     0xc5
56: 67 72 61                addr32 jb 0xba
59: 6d                      ins    DWORD PTR es:[rdi],dx
5a: 20 63 61                and    BYTE PTR [rbx+0x61],ah
5d: 6e                      outs   dx,BYTE PTR ds:[rsi]
5e: 6e                      outs   dx,BYTE PTR ds:[rsi]
5f: 6f                      outs   dx,DWORD PTR ds:[rsi]
60: 74 20                   je     0x82
62: 62                      (bad)
63: 65 20 72 75             and    BYTE PTR gs:[rdx+0x75],dh
67: 6e                      outs   dx,BYTE PTR ds:[rsi]
68: 20 69 6e                and    BYTE PTR [rcx+0x6e],ch
6b: 20 44 4f 53             and    BYTE PTR [rdi+rcx*2+0x53],al
6f: 20 6d 6f                and    BYTE PTR [rbp+0x6f],ch
72: 64 65 2e 0d 0d 0a 24    fs gs cs or eax,0x20240a0d
79: 20
7a: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
7c: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
7e: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
80: 50                      push   rax
81: 45 20 20                and    BYTE PTR [r8],r12b
84: 64 86 13                xchg   BYTE PTR fs:[rbx],dl
87: 20 24 97                and    BYTE PTR [rdi+rdx*4],ah
8a: 09 62 20                or     DWORD PTR [rdx+0x20],esp
8d: 86 01                   xchg   BYTE PTR [rcx],al
8f: 20 b6 05 20 20 f0       and    BYTE PTR [rsi-0xfdfdffb],dh
95: 20 26                   and    BYTE PTR [rsi],ah
97: 20 0b                   and    BYTE PTR [rbx],cl
99: 02 02                   add    al,BYTE PTR [rdx]
9b: 25 20 18 20 20          and    eax,0x20201820
a0: 20 40 20                and    BYTE PTR [rax+0x20],al
a3: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
a5: 02 20                   add    ah,BYTE PTR [rax]
a7: 20 d0                   and    al,dl
a9: 14 20                   adc    al,0x20
ab: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
ad: 10 20                   adc    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
af: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
b1: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
b3: 40 01 20                rex add DWORD PTR [rax],esp
b6: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
b8: 20 10                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],dl
ba: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
bc: 20 02                   and    BYTE PTR [rdx],al
be: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
c0: 04 20                   add    al,0x20
c2: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
c4: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
c6: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
c8: 05 20 02 20 20          add    eax,0x20200220
cd: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
cf: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
d1: 40 02 20                add    spl,BYTE PTR [rax]
d4: 20 06                   and    BYTE PTR [rsi],al
d6: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
d8: cf                      iret
d9: ea                      (bad)
da: 02 20                   add    ah,BYTE PTR [rax]
dc: 03 20                   add    esp,DWORD PTR [rax]
de: 60                      (bad)
df: 01 20                   add    DWORD PTR [rax],esp
e1: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
e3: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
e5: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
e7: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
e9: 10 20                   adc    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
eb: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
ed: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
ef: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
f1: 20 10                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],dl
f3: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
f5: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
f7: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
f9: 10 20                   adc    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
fb: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
fd: 20 20                   and    BYTE PTR [rax],ah
ff: 20                      .byte 0x20
```

Comment: The exe file has a specific format, it includes headers and metadata. It is not simply a dump of machine code. For example, the first two bytes are the signature `MZ`. See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) You can use a disassembler that understands the exe format if you want to look at the code.

Comment: Windows has nothing to do with the opcodes because instructions are only executed by the CPU. But if you treat the raw bytes of an executable as code then obviously it'll just print in bogus results because executable files contain more than just instructions. Disassemble raw bytes of Linux ELF files will also do the same thing

Answer (score 3):

Not all bytes in the .exe are meant to be executed.  The [.exe file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) consists of several tables that tell the OS how to load the executable into memory, and how to start it.  What you're seeing in the listing above are the data tables that are meant for the OS to read and analyze, but not execute.

Specifically, each Windows executable is also a DOS executable.  This is why the first two bytes of each file are M and Z -- those are initials of Mark Zbikowski -- the lead of the DOS 2.0 development team who designed the format.  The DOS part of your executable only outputs a message that this program is designed to work on Windows, and exits.  This way, if your executable is started on a DOS machine, the user will know what's going on.

However, if your executable is started on a Windows machine, the Windows loader knows how to bypass the DOS part, verify that the Windows part can be loaded (e.g. it's 32-bit or 64-bit, it's for Intel or ARM or PowerPC architecture, etc.), and then load the parts of the file into the memory and start running it.